# Tomcat fails deploying and old webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, resin

I get blocked trying to move an old webapp developed for Resin server (without creating a war container or having ejb-jar.xml) to a Tomcat 7 server. What I´ve done is: create a Dynamic Web project in Eclipse, include the code and created ejb-jar with the declaration. Also created the web.xml file with the servlet. Once it compiled correctly, I exported it to a WAR file which I deploy in Tomcat.

This is the error:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/PortalSavia-Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ejb/EJBObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1845)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredMethods(Introspection.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadMethodsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

I´ve checked ejb-jar.xml which is in META-INF as It must be. Also web.xml seems to be fine and have the servlet. Any idea where to look for an error? Maybe libs? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat is not a full application server, it is just a servlet container. That being said, Tomcat does not have JAVA EE container.

The javax/ejb/EJBObject can be found in the Java EE jars. So either user a full application server like JBoss, or include the necessary JAR's in Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat does not support EJBs.  It is just a servlet container.  You need to use a *full* Java EE application container, such a JBoss, Glassfish or WebSphere.

I would NOT recommend trying to add the EJB support jars to a vanilla Tomcat installation.  It is / they are not designed to be used that way, and you are likely to run into lots of problems.

Comment: heh... sir, you're the first person suggesting to use WebSphere :)

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using tomcat you can try to deploy your application to [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html)

TomEE - is basically tomcat with J2EE steroids. I'm sure that your app won't run out of the box (usually applications tie themselves to the application servers so tightly, that it's impossible to change the application server).

I suggest you take a look at a full-blown J2EE application server (JBoss, Glassfish etc).